# Loop over list of dataframes applying various functions in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, pivot

I am struggling to apply various functions to a list of 60 dataframes. Mainly I want to use select and pivot_longer, but I also need to transform some variables to numerics. For some reason, the solutions I found are not working. Basically I need to do three things:

First, read in all excel sheets (there are more than these two, obviously)

```
df1 <- readxl::read_xlsx("C:/Users/.../df_list.xlsx", skip = 3, col_names = T, sheet = "df_1")
df2 <- readxl::read_xlsx("C:/Users/.../df_list.xlsx", skip = 3, col_names = T, sheet = "df_2")
```

Second, I want to pivot longer, unselect some

```
df1 <- df1  %>%  
  pivot_longer(!c("country", "type", "company", "sector", "name"), names_to = "year", values_to = "df1") %>%
  select(!name)

df2 <- df2  %>%  
  pivot_longer(!c("country", "type", "company", "sector", "name"), names_to = "year", values_to = "df1") %>%
  select(!name)
```

Third, I want combine into one dataframe

```
df <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2,
            by = c("country", "type", "company", "sector", "name", "year"))
```

Since there are not two, but more excel sheets containing different variables, I want to put these in lists and loop over it applying all the same functions.

The first step I managed using the following:

```
mysheets_fromexcel <- list()
mysheetlist <- excel_sheets(path="C:/Users/.../df_list.xlsx")
i=1
for (i in 1:length(mysheetlist)){
  tempdf <- read_excel(path="C:/Users/.../df_list.xlsx", sheet = mysheetlist[i], skip = 3, col_names = T)
  tempdf$sheetname <- mysheetlist[i]
  mysheets_fromexcel[[i]] <- tempdf 
}
```

Now I have something that looks like the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame("type" = c("679821", "2800K7", "31938W", "749352", "15437R"),
                  "company" = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                  "sector" = c("AA", "BB", "BB", "CC", "DD"),
                  "name" = c("A - var1", "B - var1", "C - var1", "D - var1" ,"E - var1"),
                  "country" = c("US", "US", "UK", "UK", "DE"),
                  "2010" = c(NA, 9999, 9999, NA, NA),
                  "2011" = c("Y", "9999", NA, "N", "9999"),
                  "2012" = c("Y", "9999", "N", "N", "9999"))

df2 <- data.frame("type" = c("679821", "2800K7", "31938W", "749352", "15437R"),
                  "company" = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                  "sector" = c("AA", "BB", "BB", "CC", "DD"),
                  "name" = c("A - var2", "B - var2", "C - var2", "D - var2" ,"E - var2"),
                  "country" = c("US", "US", "UK", "UK", "DE"),
                  "2010" = c(NA, 9999, NA, NA, NA),
                  "2011" = c("N", "N", NA, "9999", "9999"),
                  "2012" = c("Y", "9999", "Y", "Y", "9999"))

mylist <- list(A = df1, B = df2)
```

Not that not all values in columns "2010", "2011", "2012" are of the same class: some are numeric, some character. To pivot, I think these need to be of the same class. Ideally, I would first recode these, which in an individual dataframe would look something like:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(y2010 = case_when(y2010 == "Y" ~ 1,
                           y2010 == "N" ~ 0,
                           y2010 == 9999 ~ NA_real_),
         y2011 = case_when(y2011 == "Y" ~ 1,
                           y2011 == "N" ~ 0,
                           y2011 == 9999 ~ NA_real_),
         y2012 = case_when(y2012 == "Y" ~ 1,
                           y2012 == "N" ~ 0,
                           y2012 == 9999 ~ NA_real_))
```

But then ideally for this set of variables, and for all dataframes in the list.

Then to pivot I tried:

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) x %>% pivot_longer(!c("country", "type", "company", "sector", "name"), names_to = "year", values_to = mylist[i]))
```

It doesnt work..

Eventually, it should look like:

```
type   company sector country year    df1   df2
<chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
679821 A       AA     US      y2010    NA    NA
679821 A       AA     US      y2011     1     0
679821 A       AA     US      y2012     1     1
2800K7 B       BB     US      y2010    NA    NA
2800K7 B       BB     US      y2011    NA     0
2800K7 B       BB     US      y2012    NA    NA
31938W C       BB     UK      y2010    NA    NA
31938W C       BB     UK      y2011    NA    NA
31938W C       BB     UK      y2012     0     1
749352 D       CC     UK      y2010    NA    NA
749352 D       CC     UK      y2011     0    NA
749352 D       CC     UK      y2012     0     1
15437R E       DD     DE      y2010    NA    NA
15437R E       DD     DE      y2011    NA    NA
15437R E       DD     DE      y2012    NA    NA
```

Sorry for the very long question. There's a few steps, but the baseline is that I need to loop over large lists of dataframes and I can't figure out exactly how to.

Comment: If you rename the list elements to 'A', 'B', the column names would be A, B and not df1, df2.  When you create the list, use `list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)` to get the expected output

Answer (score 3):

We may use `imap` to loop over the `list`, convert to long format with `pivot_longer` specify the `values_to` from the names of the list (`.y`), join the list elements with `reduce` and modify the column values

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
imap(mylist, ~ .x %>%   
   select(-name) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -c("country", "type", "company", "sector"), 
     names_to = "year", values_to = .y, 
      values_transform = as.character)) %>%
   reduce(left_join)%>%
   mutate(across(all_of(names(mylist)), 
  ~ case_when(.x == "Y" ~ 1, .x == "N" ~ 0)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 × 7
   type   company sector country year      A     B
   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 679821 A       AA     US      X2010    NA    NA
 2 679821 A       AA     US      X2011     1     0
 3 679821 A       AA     US      X2012     1     1
 4 2800K7 B       BB     US      X2010    NA    NA
 5 2800K7 B       BB     US      X2011    NA     0
 6 2800K7 B       BB     US      X2012    NA    NA
 7 31938W C       BB     UK      X2010    NA    NA
 8 31938W C       BB     UK      X2011    NA    NA
 9 31938W C       BB     UK      X2012     0     1
10 749352 D       CC     UK      X2010    NA    NA
11 749352 D       CC     UK      X2011     0    NA
12 749352 D       CC     UK      X2012     0     1
13 15437R E       DD     DE      X2010    NA    NA
14 15437R E       DD     DE      X2011    NA    NA
15 15437R E       DD     DE      X2012    NA    NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I am quite close. Applying to the actual data I get the following error: Error in `build_longer_spec()`:
! `values_to` must be a vector with type <character>.
Instead, it has type <integer>.

Comment: Thanks. So the column names are `2010`, `2011`, ... , `2023` (including the ` ` ). Im not great with regular expressions, what would be the right pattern for that?

Comment: Hm, neither the mutate step nor the values_transform work. Both give me the same error. The mutate step does seem to work, if I run the code up until pivot_longer all 2010 ... 2023 variables are character class. What else could be wrong?

Comment: The problem must be with the column names? That option doesn't work either. The column names are: "Type"               "ESG Company Name"   "ICB SECTOR NAME"    "ISO CODE -DOMICILE" "Name"               "2010"               "2011"               "2012"              
"2013"               "2014"               "2015"               "2016"               "2017"               "2018"               "2019"               "2020"              
"2021"               "2022"               "2023"               "sheetname"

Comment: Yes thanks, I did change that accordingly. Might the problem be with the structure of the list? If I check the structure of one of the 63 data frames in the list of dataframes,, using `str(mylistl[1])`, all the individual variables are character, but the entire thing is: `tibble [2,583 x 20] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)`. If so, is the for loop to load the different excel sheets into a list the correct way to go about?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251368/discussion-between-joost-maxen-and-akrun).

Comment: What actually works is to change `values_to` to `values_to = as.character(.y)`. I don't know why `values_transform` in `pivot_longer` does not work, I am not familiar with that function. Now the problem is that the variables are titled "1" and "2", where ideally they are titled as the excel sheet. Also, `mutate(across(all_of(names(mysheets_fromexcel)), ~ case_when(.x == "Y" ~ 1, .x == "N" ~ 0)))` does not work and `names(mysheets_fromexcel)` gives me `NULL`. Is the problem with the first step, reading in the excel sheets?

Comment: I can't edit the comment anymore, but I think I found the problem. The names in the list were numeric (1,2,3,4 ... 63) and you cannot give a numeric value to a column name. I added `names(mysheets_fromexcel)[i] <- mysheetlist[i]` in the loop loading my excel sheets, and now the code works. Thanks a lot for all the help !